# CASE WHEN usage in Phalcon models manager doesn't give the right value

Tags: mysql, sql, phalcon, phalcon-orm

While looking at some code from my controller I saw that there is a weird bug on a query, basically on the case when statements :

Database content :

columns :

```
category : client or case category
type : title or content
mainpage 1 or 0 (true or false)
```

values :

```
0;0;1
```

corresponding to the normal output :

```
Case category;title;yes
```

current output :

```
Client;Content;No
```

PHQL :

```
SELECT content.id,
(CASE content WHEN content.category = 0 THEN 'Case category' WHEN content.category = 1 THEN 'Client' WHEN content.category = 2 THEN 'Case' WHEN content.category = 3 THEN 'Product' WHEN content.category = 4 THEN 'Product category' WHEN content.category = 5 THEN 'Team' WHEN content.category = 6 THEN 'Vacancy' WHEN content.category = 7 THEN 'Reference' WHEN content.category = 8 THEN 'Article' ELSE "Category not found" END) AS category 

FROM Apps\Source\Models\MainContent AS content 
GROUP BY content.id
```

The fact is that all the 'case when' statements return the wrong value even tho (ex : content.category = 0 in the database, but it gets me 'Client event tho it's supposed to get it for a value of 1)

If I translate the statement into pure sql, just for the case, to test it, it works...

```
SELECT 
content.id,
(CASE WHEN content.category = 0 THEN 'Case category' WHEN content.category = 1 THEN 'Client' WHEN content.category = 2 THEN 'Case' WHEN content.category = 3 THEN 'Product' WHEN content.category = 4 THEN 'Product category' WHEN content.category = 5 THEN 'Team' WHEN content.category = 6 THEN 'Vacancy' WHEN content.category = 7 THEN 'Reference' WHEN content.category = 8 THEN 'Article' ELSE "Category not found" END) AS category 

FROM main_content AS content 
GROUP BY content.id
```

output :

```
Case category;title;yes
```

Is this a phql oddity ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between both statements (raw sql is searched case, PHQL is simple): in PHQL try

```
SELECT content.id,
(CASE WHEN ...
```

With so many cases, wouldn't it be better to make a "Category" lookup table and join it with "main_content"?